# ListView overlaps textview and background image in android

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to design layout but its not rendering properly. Background logo is not visible at all. When phone goes to landscape mode then textview below listview is not visible.

[image]

Below is my xml.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#E0ECF8"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.view.MainMenuActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E0ECF8" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/note1Wrapper_note1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2_note1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:text="@string/note1"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="13sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#0c2d4e"
            android:src="@drawable/banner640" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:text="@string/menu_title"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/View1_hr"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1_title"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="#80000000" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/View1_hr"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="#E0ECF8" >
        </ListView>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/View2_hr"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#80000000" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: change your RelativeLayout to linear layout. and set its orientation to vertical, use layout weights to adjust your views sizes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem may come from using `ListView` inside `ScrollView`. You should avoid it. To overcome your problem, I think you can set a specific height for your `ListView` or using a vertical `LinearLayout` to add row views programmatically.

> Using a ListView to make it not scroll is extremely expensive and goes against the whole purpose of ListView. You should NOT do this. Just use a LinearLayout instead. - from Romain Guy - the developer who write `ListView` in GG.

Answer (score 1):

ok the problem is there with your definition, just define your `LinearLayout` below `View` (which is below`ListView`). check this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="#E0ECF8"
 android:fillViewport="true"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context="com.example.view.MainMenuActivity" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#0c2d4e"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:text="MEnu"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/View1_hr"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="#80000000" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/View1_hr"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="#E0ECF8" >
    </ListView>

     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/note1Wrapper_note1"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_gravity="start"
         android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
         android:background="#E0ECF8"
         android:gravity="start"
         android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2_note1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:text="Nofghnjfgjtyjjyjdtyjte"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

output :

[image: out]

Comment: can you share you water mark logo..so that I can post full xml with output

Comment: I can not give logo but its same as http://www.mantisbt.org/docs/tmp/en-US/xml/Common_Content/images/watermark-draft.png having  200x200 in size.  Also see Textview below listview should not overlap each other.

Answer (score 0):

May be that is what you need?

**UPDATE:**

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#E0ECF8"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.view.MainMenuActivity" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#E0ECF8" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/View1_hr"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:background="#E0ECF8"
            android:layout_above="@+id/note1Wrapper_note1">
        </ListView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/note1Wrapper_note1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2_note1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:text="@string/note1"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="13sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#0c2d4e"
            android:src="@drawable/banner640" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:text="@string/menu_title"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/View1_hr"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1_title"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="#80000000" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/View2_hr"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="#80000000" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I updated own answer, try again. I dont understand the whole problem, you want do like on this image? http://i.stack.imgur.com/nKr2T.png

Comment: I am trying to make layout in which logo will be at header part, watermarked logo will be in background and listview and textview vertically aligned.